# LinkedIn article wrong read time calculation

Tags: javascript, html, linkedin-api

For my project, we are sharing an article on the main website via LinkedIn. LinkedIn says it's read time is only one minute long, while the article's content is pretty large.

Our first guess is that LinkedIn calculates the read time based on the cookie popup, which always shows, GDPR-wise.

Does someone know if this can be the case, and if so, if there's a way to circumvent the popup, or to set the read time in an OG tag or something?

Kind regards,
Bertijn